# Pagination level2 - scrapy python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I had to make a scraper, and i don't understand why it don't work ...

The website have a pagination like that:

```
<div class="pagination toolbarbloc">
        <ul>
                <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
                <li><a href="...">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="...">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="...">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="...">5</a></li>
                <li><a class="end" href="...">>></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The class "active" move when you go next page, so in page 5, it's the balise "li" just before the last one who have the class active !
I catch the item after the balise "li" with class "active" like that:

```
next_page_url_xpath = '//div[@class="pagination toolbarbloc"]/ul/li[@class="active"]/following-sibling::li/a/@href'
```

It work perfectly for the 5 first page ... but it doesn't work to go page 6 catch the balise "a" with class end ...

I try that:

```
    try:
        next_page_url_xpath = '//div[@class="pagination toolbarbloc"]/ul/li[@class="active"]/following-sibling::li/a/@href'
        next_page_url = begin + response.xpath(next_page_url_xpath)[0].extract()
    except (ValueError,IndexError):
        next_page_url_xpath = '//div[@class="pagination toolbarbloc"]/ul/li/a[@class="end"]/@href'
        next_page_url = begin + response.xpath(next_page_url_xpath)[0].extract()
```

Someone have an idea ? :)
Thank's for ure help !

Answer (score 0):

```
import codecs
from lxml import etree

test_xml = """<div class="pagination toolbarbloc">
        <ul>
                <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
                <li><a href="1href">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="2href">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="3href">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="4href">5</a></li>
                <li><a class="end" href="5href">>></li>
        </ul>
</div>"""

tree = etree.HTML(test_xml)
rep = tree.xpath('//div[@class="pagination toolbarbloc"]/ul/li/a/@href')

print rep
# ['1href', '2href', '3href', '4href', '5href']
```

I wonder if I quite understand what you said. If you truely want same python function like this, maybe it can help you.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for you're help !
I try to do what you say but i don't understand why it doesn't return the last page ... I have:

['/vente-immobilier/annonces-vente-terrain-u26p2.html', '/vente-immobilier/annonces-vente-terrain-u26p3.html', '/vente-immobilier/annonces-vente-terrain-u26p4.html', '/vente-immobilier/annonces-vente-terrain-u26p5.html']

There is no page 6 ... :/

Comment: could you get the same result in my example? If you get the same result in my example but could not get you want in real scrapy work, maybe xml format are different.

Comment: I try in my scrapy but it didn't work ...
the url is http://www.topannonces.fr/vente-immobilier/annonces-vente-terrain-u26.html

I don't understand why it fail really ...

Comment: I check you [URL](http://www.topannonces.fr/vente-immobilier/annonces-vente-terrain-u26.html) and find last one(balise "a" with class) have NO `@herf` but `ref`