# Scrapy parse pagination without next link

Tags: parsing, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to parse a pagination without next link. The html is belove:

```
<div id="pagination" class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="//www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name" class="page-1 ">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name?page=2" class="page-2 ">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name?page=3" class="page-3 ">3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name?page=4" class="page-4 active">4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name?page=5" class="page-5">5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name?page=6" class="page-6 ">6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <span class="page-... three-dots">...</span>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="//www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name?page=50" class="page-50 ">50</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

For this html I have try this xpath:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
or 
response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/ul/li/a/@href/following-sibling::a[1]/@href').extract()
```

is there a good way to parse this pagination? Thanks for all.

PS: I have checked this answers too:

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446203/scrapy-how-to-manage-pagination-without-next-button)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416198/pagination-level2-scrapy-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to scrape x number of pages, but this isn't always a good solution if the total number of pages isn't constant:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.spider):
    num_pages = 10
    def start_requests(self):
        requests = []
        for i in range(1, self.num_pages)
            requests.append(scrapy.Request(
                url='www.demopage.com/category_product_seo_name?page={0}'.format(i)
            ))
        return requests

    def parse(self, response):
        #parse pages here.
```

**Update**

You can also keep track of the page count and do something like this. `a[href~="?page=2"]::attr(href)` will target `a` elements which `href` attribute contains the string specified. (I'm not currently able to test if this code works, but something in the style of this should do it)

```
class MySpider(scrapy.spider):
    start_urls = ['https://demopage.com/search?p=1']
    page_count = 1


def parse(self, response):
     self.page_count += 1
     #parse response

     next_url = response.css('#pagination > ul > li > a[href~="?page={0}"]::attr(href)'.format(self.page_count))
     if next_url:
         yield scrapy.Request(
             url = next_url
         )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as you say this is not a good solution. This is just a one result. I have several results like this and some are finishing with 50 and some with 5 pages.

Comment: I have tested and next_url is returning empty.

Comment: Hi, I have forget to give a feedback for your solution. With a little modification it's worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get all the pagination links and run it inside the loop every time you have to call the below code and available pagination links will be returned by the selector. You don't need to worry about duplicate URLs as scrapy will handle this one for you. You can also use scrapy Rules as well.

```
 response.css('.pagination ::attr(href)').getall()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I think there must be another way to doing this. before I asked this question I had the same solution with this response.css('div.pagination ul li a::attr(href)').extract()