# Scrapy - Pagination without next page (Python)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape [the following page](https://www.workana.com/jobs)

I can't figure out how to define a rule for navigate into the pagination, because this page doesn't have a next button.

Code

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        allow=(), restrict_xpaths='')),
)
```

Comment: With selenium, you could target the `li` inside the `ul` tag with class name `pagination`. Can you do something similar with scrapy?

Comment: `https://www.workana.com/jobs?page=2` iterate over this link and change 2 till the page found or may be 50

Comment: I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244175/scrapy-parse-pagination-without-next-link/63244393#63244393